# Children's book about a long neck blue alien wearing a turtle neck sweater

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

I read a book in the 1980s that I am looking for title and publish date.

Book Type: children's picture book

Plot:
A long necked blue alien visits earth and disguises themselves by wearing a turtleneck sweater.

Comment: If you remember anything else about this, for example, any plot elements or what happens, please [edit] your question to add that in. Also can you remember why the alien came to Earth or what he did when there?

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking of Mel Gilden's _[Surfing Samurai Robots](https://books.google.com/books/about/Surfing_Samurai_Robots.html?id=ZHDuw4L6Xq4C&source=kp_book_description)_, but that's not exactly a children's book. Maybe YA at a stretch.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.